# twig customizing form_row with form_theme

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to remove 'div' from form_row block using form_theme like this:

```
{% form_theme feedback_form _self %}

{% block form_row %}
    {{ form_label(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{% endblock %}

{{ form_start(feedback_form) }}
    {{ form_row(feedback_form.name) }}
    {{ form_row(feedback_form.email) }}
    {{ form_row(feedback_form.subject) }}
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
{{ form_end(feedback_form) }}
```

just like it is said in Doc https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/form_customization.html#customizing-the-form-row

The trouble is that twig tries to render the {% block form_row %} right in that place of template, where it is, and the result is

> Variable "form" does not exist.

because I don't have variable 'form' in this template.

The template is rendered by separate action in the footer of page, and it doesn't extend anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution while was writing the question.

Putting the code of form_row block to the separate file solves the problem.

```
{# feedback_form.html.twig #}
{% form_theme feedback_form 'fields.html.twig' %}

{{ form_start(feedback_form) }}
    {{ form_row(feedback_form.name) }}
    {{ form_row(feedback_form.email) }}
    {{ form_row(feedback_form.subject) }}
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
{{ form_end(feedback_form) }}

{# fields.html.twig #}
{% block form_row %}
    {{ form_label(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Extending another template helps too.

```
{# base.html.twig #}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

{# feedback_form.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme feedback_form _self %}

{% block form_row %}
    {{ form_label(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{ form_start(feedback_form) }}
        {{ form_row(feedback_form.name) }}
        {{ form_row(feedback_form.email) }}
        {{ form_row(feedback_form.subject) }}
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    {{ form_end(feedback_form) }}
{% endblock %}
```